# a colloquial way of asking whether or not I can get to a place on foot

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm looking for ways of expressing or asking if a place is reachable on foot.

Can I say "Is this place within walking distance?" or "Am I within walking distance of this place?"

Also is it ok to say "is this place walkable?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first two options are fine. "Is this place walkable?" makes it sound as if you are asking if you can walk ***on the place*** rather than walk to it. "Is it too far to walk?" is another option. I would also recommend that you learn about asking distances from one place to another, if you haven't already.

Comment: so you mean, "Is this place within walking distance?" or "Am I within walking distance of this place?" are both ok?

Comment: They are fine. You should be readily understood by anyone who can understand English.